# Accords des qualificatifs

Tags: accord

J'ai un doute sur les accords des qualificatifs : « ces feuilles ressemblent à des langues de chats ». C'est ma formulation instinctive mais elle me dérange :

- langues de chats : ça peut signifier que plusieurs chats ont plusieurs langues chacun
- langue de chats : plusieurs chats avec une seule langue pour tous
- langues de chat : un chat avec plusieurs langues
- langue de chat : un chat une langue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comme la plupart des compléments du nom de cette forme, *chat* qualifie *langue*, mais ne s'accorde pas avec lui : **des langues de chat**. Notons qu'on pourrait avoir aussi *des langues-de-chat*.

Voir notamment à la fin de [l'article du TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/langue-de-chat).